# matplotlib bar chart with overlapping dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I am plotting a simple bar chart using `pandas`/`matplotlib`. The x-axis is a datetime index. There are so many datapoints that the labels overlap. Is there an easy solution for this problem, no matter if I have daily, weekly, monthly, or yearly data?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range("2015-01-01", "2021-09-30", freq="b")
data = np.random.randn(len(idx))

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"returns": data}, index=idx)

df.plot(kind="bar")

plt.show()
```

[image: Bar plot with overlapping dates on x-axis]

Comment: It should be plotted as a line plot, The data is continuous. Remove `kind='bar'`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney What about monthly or yearly data?

Comment: If you aggregate the data by month or year (e.g. `mean` or `sum`), then a bar is probably more appropriate. You can make it `kind='barh'` since it's not constrained by the width of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateFormatter` to custom the xaxis but let Matplotlib handle the figure rather than Pandas:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# ...

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 7))
ax.bar(df.index, df['returns'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
```

[image: DateFormatter]

Comment: The DateFormatter provides incorrect dates. These dates are not in the ``DatetimeIndex``. Also, I'm definitely looking for a bar chart. And the formatting should dynamically adjust to the ``DatetimeIndex``, which belongs to the ``pd.DataFrame``.

Comment: What is your aggregate function?

Comment: I don't use an aggregate function. I do have a ``pd.Dataframe`` containing returns for e.g. daily, monthly, or yearly timeframes. Data and timeframe are given.

Comment: @Andi. I updated my answer. I think it's what you are looking for. Can you check that, please?

Comment: Now the dates seem to be OK. However, when I change the ``freq`` argument to, let's say, ``Y``, I don't see any bars at all. Can you replicate this issue?